# Find the derivative of the function when given an exponential function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y=5{x^2}e^{3x}$

Would the rule that I use for this problem be $\frac{d}{dx} e^x=e^x$

We just started learning derivatives of exponential functions and I am a little confused on where to start with this problem.

Answer choices are

A. $10xe^{3x}(2x+3)$

B. $5xe^{3x}(2x+3)$

C. $10xe^{3x}(3x+2)$ This is the answer choice that I believe to be correct after trying to simplify

D. $5xe^{3x}(3x+2)$

Comment: You use the product rule and the more general $\frac{d}{dx} e^{ax}=ae^{ax}$

Comment: So is my answer correct?

Comment: Pretty sure it's D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $y = 5x^2e^{3x}$, notice that you must use the product rule since there are two functions of $x$ defined by y. Using this, you have $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 5[ (x^2)' \cdot e^{3x} + x^2 \cdot (e^{3x})']. $$ Now, you use the basic differentiation rules to find this.

You can then get $$5[2x \cdot e^{3x} + x^2 \cdot e^{3x} \cdot \frac{d}{dx} (3x)] $$ or $$5[2xe^{3x} + 3x^2e^{3x}] = 5xe^{3x}(2 + 3x).$$

So to answer your question, you have to use the product rule and chain rule along with the rule that $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dx}5{x^2}e^{3x}=5\frac{d}{dx}{x^2}e^{3x}=5\bigg[\bigg(x^2\frac{d}{dx}e^{3x}\bigg)+\bigg(e^{3x}\frac{d}{dx}x^2\bigg)\bigg]=5(x^23e^{3x}+e^{3x}2x)=5xe^{3x}(3x+2)$$

Answer (score 0):

When you only have products and/or quotients, logarithmic differentiation makes life much easier.

For example, in your case $$y=5{x^2}e^{3x}\implies \log(y)=\log(5)+2\log(x)+3x$$ Differentiating gives $$\frac{y'}y=\frac 2x+3\implies y'=\left(\frac 2x+3\right)y=\left(\frac 2x+3\right)5{x^2}e^{3x}=5 x (3 x+2)e^{3x}$$